# How to get parent recyclerview value in nested recyclerview after clicking child recyclerview

Tags: android, firebase

Iam using nested recyclerview
I need to  get data of parent recyclerview when I clicked child recyclerview its possible..

Iiam using Firebase recycler adapter

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason you need to have nested recyclerview's and it does slow down performance because it was intentionally designed not to be nested(Although it does actually show correctly).

Comment: If any other method please suggests me..

Comment: What goal are you trying to accomplish?